# Sorting Elements of multidimensional Array at a certain Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an Array of Arrays. My Array is

*splitarr[Array0[],Array3[],Array[2],Array[1],Array[4]...]*

It is not ordered correctly as you see, I want to order it so it would look something like that.

*splitarr[Array0[],Array1[],Array2[],Array3[],Array[4]...]*

To understand the whole thing better. There are various "functions" which determine where the array will be sorted. So far I have written a function which orders the array correctly when the "index", where it is ordered incorrectly is 0. But to fully explain how I know where it is ordered incorrectly would take too long to explain.

```
var dividersecond = 2;
```

The "divider second", derives from a function. But what is important to know in this context, is that my array is ordered incorrectly at those amount of Positions like this for example:

*splitarr[Array2[],Array1[],Array0[],Array3[]...]*

```
var splitarrayindex = 0;
```

This is the Index of the Array at which the incorrect order starts.

```
mySplitArray = ReorderArray(dividersecond,splitarrayindex,mySplitArray);

function ReorderArray(Count,Index,Array){
    var originalIndex = Index;

    for(Index;Index<Count-1;Index++){
        var swapIndex= (Count-Index);
        var temp = Array[Index];
        Array[Index] = Array[swapIndex];
        Array[swapIndex] = temp
    }
    Array.splice(originalIndex,1);
    return Array;
}
```

This function works, as long as the index is 0. Which makes sense.
One of my problems is *"Count-1"*, in the *"for-loop"*. When my Index is "0", and 3 Elements (divider = 2) are ordered *incorrectly*, I of course need *"2" Times of swapping*. If my Index is "1", then *"Count-1"*, would mess with this.

There are other things that determine wether my Array will be ordered correctly, for Example determining the Current Index and the Current Swap Index. 
All of this and the fact that I am new to Javascript and sorting Arrays, leave me solutionless. If someone could help me with a function that would be awsome!

Here is a quick description of what I wanna do in my Code. (Visualized with Numbers)

2103

(swap at 0 and 2)

0123

> Code like this works already because the Index is 0

03214

(Swap Index 1 and Index 3)

01234

> How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solved the Problem. Not entirely sure yet. But I will try it with other numbers and Indexes, to see wether it works.

```
function ReorderArray(Count,Index,Array){
  var originalIndex = Index;
  for(var i = 0; i<Count-1;i++){
    var swapIndex = ((Count+originalIndex)-i);
    var temp = Array[originalIndex+i];
    Array[originalIndex+i] = Array[swapIndex];
    Array[swapIndex] = temp;
  }
  //delete the position at the original Index
  Array.splice(originalIndex,1);
  return Array;
}
```